# Apply generic to each member of union: How to get from Some<1 | 2 | 3> to Some<1> | Some<2> | Some<3>

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Since I failed to create a minimal reproducible example for my problem, this is an abstract version. I have a situation where the "order of appliance" matters in nested generics.

```
type Some<A> = {type: A}
type Union1 = Some<1 | 2 | 3>
type Union2 = Some<1> | Some<2> | Some<3>
```

Is there a way to get from Union1 to Union2? In my real code A is an object I'm pattern matching on... which works for Union2, but I got Union1. Hope that makes sense.

```
type HowTo<???> = ???
type Result = HowTo<Union1> // returns Some<1> | Some<2> | Some<3>
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgHgIID4oF4oG8qiQBcUqUAvgNwBQh0AqgHYCWcjAjNrIipwD5QATFAEBmdDVrhoACTgB3ACpxkiqBAAewCIwAmAZ25JkAQ0Yh0mHGs3a9h+MeaMAZhABOUeumpQoAfi91LR0DL18-AKMUbwi-EkYIADcPCITkj0k6KAAlCH0AVwAbYC45JRUmVg4JaiA) work for you?  If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Yes, that works. Curious how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `T` in `Some<T>` we will need to use the [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) keyword:

```
type HowTo<T extends Some<any>> = T extends Some<infer U> ? U : never

// 1 | 2 | 3
type Result = HowTo<Some<1 | 2 | 3>>
```

Not, we need to [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) the *union* to make sure that we wrap each member of the union *individually*, which can be done with the `extends` operator. The condition must be always true to make sure that every member of the union is in place. We can use `extends any` or `extends T` since `T` always extends itself or `any`. The following code after the distribution will be called for each member of the union:

```
type HowTo<T extends Some<any>> = T extends Some<infer U>
  ? U extends U
    ? Some<U>
    : never
  : never;
```

Testing:

```
// Some<1> | Some<2> | Some<3>
type Result = HowTo<Union1>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgHgIID4oF4oG8qiQBcUqUAvgNwBQh0AqgHYCWcjAjNrIipwD5QATFAEBmdDVrhoACTgB3ACpxkiqBAAewCIwAmAZ25JkAQ0Yh0mHGs3a9h+MeaMAZhABOUeumpQoAfi91LR0DL18-AKMUbwi-EkYIADcPCITkj0kAeizo5HZMAUcUQUK88SlIKAAlCH0AVwAbYC45JRUmVg4JaiA)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite as elegant as @wonderflame, but here's my approach using an extra type that extracts the union type from `Some<1 | 2 |3>` defined in `Union1`. Then you can use a mapped type which maps the union to an object that looks like this `{ 1: Some<1>; 2: Some<2>; 3: Some<3>; }`. Finally, you can transform that object back to a union by accessing the individual keys using the union type we extracted in the first place.

```
type Some<A> = {type: A};
type Union1 = Some<1 | 2 | 3>;

type ExtractUnion<T> = T extends Some<infer U> ? U : never;
// ExtractUnion<Union1> -> 1 | 2 | 3

type HowTo<T extends Some<any>> = {
  [K in ExtractUnion<T>]: Some<K>;
}[ExtractUnion<T>];

type Result = HowTo<Union1>; // Some<1> | Some<2> | Some<3>
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgHgIID4oF4oG9SQBcUqAvgNwCwAUAdAKoB2AlnIwIzayIqcA%20UAExQBAZnRVqNOlACiAD2AAnAIYBjYE1aNkAFUw5dUCIoiMAJgGduSZM0YAzCEqj1MAfldRijCADdnSQB6ILlFVQ0tNmQojkwAWkx%20IREoURppcGgACTgAd104PWNTC2t4WxVGEHQDPBooKABtAGkoezDldU0WaP0AXWIKlBaJGlImhS7I3p0ByUzIKAAlCEsAVwAbYC5cgqLY9jHqIA)